# Rails: Model and model template interaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, validation

**Using**: Ruby on Rails (3.0.3)

I am building a website where one can perform different health and diet related calculations.

Each calculation holds different **inputs:**

**Calculation 1**
height, weight, waist_measurement

**Calculation 2**
weight, hip_measurement

**Calculation 3**
hip_measurement, lifestyle_type (string), age, calory_intake

...and so on.

I have (as a suggestion from a friend who knows RoR) created a model "Calculation" (which stands as a template) and another model "CalculationSheet" that will be used as an instance model etc.

Model:Calculation (the template) holds data like:
- TypeOfCalculation ('health', 'lifestyle' etc)
- SearchTags
- isSpecial (a boolean to isolate certain special Calculations)

There are as many Calculation objects as there are calculation "types" on the website (such as the 3 I mentioned earlier)

Model: CalculationSheet will only hold data like:
- Result (such as BMI=>22)

A CalculationSheet will be created when a calculation is performed on the website using Create. I have no need to save these calculations (prefer not to actually).

The most important reason for using the CalculationSheet model is to be able to **validate the input**...and here is the problem.

**Problem:**
How do I validate inputs from a model that does not hold each input as an attribute. I cannot make an attribute for each type of input (there are literally 100's), such as height, weight, life_style, waist, age etc...

This is my plan as for now:

```
class CalculationSheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calculation

  # BMI
  validates :height, :numericality => true, :if => :calculation_is_bmi?
  validates :weight, :numericality => true, :if => :calculation_is_bmi?

  def calculation_is_bmi?
    # do something
  end  
end
```

which (obviously) does not work. It tries to validate height which does not exist.

What I would like to do is to "validates params[:height], :numer... etc" but it does not seem to work either...

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ActiveModel` instead of `ActiveRecord` as shown in these lines:

```
class CalculationSheet
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :height, :weight
  validates_numericality_of :height, :weight
end
```

This will allow for form validation of every attribute, but you don't store anything. Here's a great post by Yehuda Katz about `ActiveModel`: [ActiveModel: Make Any Ruby Object Feel Like ActiveRecord](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/)

For Rails 3 use `validates_with` to use a custom validator.
See [this great post](http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/building-ruby-on-rails-3-custom-validators) for information on how to use them.

*edit*:

How about this:

```
class CalculationSheet
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :height, :weight, :hip_circumference
  validates_numericality_of :height, :weight, :if => :bmi?
  validates_numericality_of :height, :hip_circumference, :if => :bai?

  def bmi?
    [height, weight].all?(&:present?)
  end

  def bmi
    weight / (height**2)
  end

  def bai?
    [height, :hip_circumference].all?(&:present?)
  end

  def bai
    (hip_circumference / height**1.5) − 18
  end

end
```

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: I don't understand your comment. What?

Comment: I can make this work, which is a good step on the way. My next, important, question is however **how can I make this generic** so I can create (and validate) :height & :weight for Calculation A and then :waist, :hip and :weight for Calculation B, using the same model?

Comment: I think your own idea of `:if => calculation_is_bmi?` will work. (Although I'd call that function simply `bmi?` myself.) Or doesn't that solve your problem?

Comment: I've added a more extensive example in my answer.

Comment: That solved it! (or at least the part that I asked about)...I am using another variable that I use to verify in the bmi-method. Basically, @calculation == 'bmi' which returns true/false....Thanks!!

Comment: No problem! Another thing I was thinking about: Maybe you want different forms for different calculations. This would place your calculations into very specific calculation models. So: a BMI form with a BMI Calculation model and BMI validations, and the same for every other calculation you provide.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in your comment "I have no need to save these calculations":

ActiveRecord is all about providing persistence for your data (i.e. saving). **If you're just wanting to do calculations, you can use plain old ruby objects :)**

With stuff like this I'd be tempted to build a little library (perhaps in /lib now and as a gem later) that does your calculations.

Comment: That is pretty much my solution right now, which works fine to perform the calculations. It does not make it possible to perform validations though...